# which of one of the following statements implies that $a_n\to +\infty$ an $n\to \infty $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers with $a_n>0$ for all $n$. Which of one of the following statements implies that $a_n\to  +\infty$ an $n\to \infty?$

A. $a_{n+1} > a_n^3$ for all $n$.

B. $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is increasing.

C. $a_{n+1} > 3a_n$ for all $n>10^{10^{10}}$

D. $a_n > \left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^n$ for all $n$.

E. $a_n>2\sum_{k=1}^{k=n}\frac{1}{k!}$ for all $n$.

I think (b) is correct as it's an increasing sequence.

For (d) i think its $\lim a_n>e^2$

But still confused about the other options.

Comment: $a_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$ is increasing but does not tend to infinity, you can also use this sequence for part A. For D, consider the sequence $b_n=(1+\frac{3}{n})^n$

Comment: @Loobear23...good point

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @MartinR..I try to do edit my post ..sorry

Comment: I made an edit that transcribes the entire question, should be better now.

Comment: @Prometheus...thank you sir..I appricite it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**C** would be the answer, I'd say.

Let $a_{10^{{10}^{10}}} = K$, for some value $K$.
Then, for $n>10^{{10}^{10}}$,

$$a_n > 3^{n-10^{{10}^{10}}}K = 3^nA,$$
where $A = \frac{K}{3^{10^{{10}^{10}}}}$.

Since the minimum values of these $a_n$ form a geometric series, they approach $\infty$. This is also true for a definition of $a_n$ that fits with the rule in **C**.

**Edit:** Rebutting other answers

A. Consider $a_0<1$. Sequence can approach 0.

B. Consider $a_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$. Is increasing, but also approaching 1.

D. Consider $a_n = 100$. Satisfies the condition, approaches 100, not $\infty$.

E. Do the same as what I did for D.